# What happened to my comment?

Tags: discussion, deleted-comments

I left a comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186740/is-there-a-difference-between-i-and-i) expressing the the thought that it was a very hard question to Google (search) for. I did this to establish that we shouldn't be too hard on the questioner, even though it is a question that has certainly been asked before. That comment is gone. It wasn't a LMGTFY comment, so I wonder if it was misunderstood or if there's some bot that automatically deletes everything with Google in it.

Comment: Googl-- ARGHHHH

Answer (score 2):

Users can flag comments as *noise, offensive, or spam* (using the little flag icon that shows up when you mouse over a comment). If a comment accumulates three flags (more if the comment is upvoted), it's automatically deleted. That may have happened to you.

I didn't see the comment, so I can't say whether it deserved to be deleted. I do see a lot of flagged comments (in the 10k tools) that, in my opinion, shouldn't have been flagged.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. It's possible that I worded it poorly and some took it to mean "you should have Googled it"; certainly the O.P. felt it was a harsh comment. Hard to tell now since I can't see it anymore. I've never looked at the 10K tools, I probably should.